# Apply navigation animation to toolbar

Tags: android

I using one activity and many fragment to navigate in my project, but when to add the animation in action, it just make effective for fragment without toolbar.

```
// MainActivity
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.firstFragment, R.id.secondFragment), drawerLayout
        )
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(
            this, navController, appBarConfiguration
        )
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }
}


// activity_main.xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>


// navigation.xml
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.project.FirstFragment"
        android:label="FirstFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.project.SecondFragment"
        android:label="fragment_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because firstFragment and secondFragment using the same activity toolbar. So if want to apply these two fragment's toolbar with animation, I create another secondActivity binding action with firstFragment and using secondFragment as the start destination, this created another toolbar for secondFragment and do what I want.